# invalid start byte error while reading PCD files

Tags: python, runtime-error, point-clouds

I'm trying to extract data from a face dataset I found online which provides png pictures and their corresponding pcd files. However, whenever I try to extract data from the pcd files I get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 202: invalid start byte
```

I understand that this is because I'm trying to read a non-ASCII character, however, I haven't seen any people run into this problem when opening an outside source's .pcd files. Is there an error on the end of the dataset, or is there a workaround that will let me read this file. I eventually want to work towards a depth image for machine learning applications (I'm fairly new to machine learning in general).

If this is a problem with the dataset, I'd love to hear about other RGB-D face datasets, as I haven't been able to find any others that provide depth information.

If this is my problem, I'd like to know what I can do to fix it, because I have tried a number of different techniques and libraries to read the files and have only gotten this error.

Thanks!

```
import os
import math
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


filePath = "001_01_cloud.pcd"

with open(filePath, "r") as pcd_file:
    lines = [line.strip().split(" ") for line in pcd_file.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Googling for the [specification for the PCD format](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.html) says that the actual point cloud data could be stored in binary form, and I'm assuming that's what's going on here:

> DATA - specifies the data type that the point cloud data is stored in. As of version 0.7, two data types are supported: ascii and binary.

Since you're opening the file with mode `"r"`, Python will assume it's text, and will handily attempt to interpret everything as UTF-8 (by default; you can pass `encoding="..."`).

However since the format has a text header followed by text or binary data, you will need to open it in binary mode, `"rb"`. (This means reads from the file will yield `bytes` objects, not strings.)  You can then `.decode()` bytes objects into strings if you need to handle them as text.

You also shouldn't use `.readlines()` with a file like this; the binary data that follows the textual headers can contain `\n` characters, and that data would be "broken" if split into lines.

Anyway, you may be reinventing the wheel here; [there seems to be a Python library for PCD files](https://github.com/dimatura/pypcd).

Comment: I've tried using that library before but there appears to be some issues, which may be self-created. I used the example code as written (inserting my file name) and it gives me "AttributeError: module 'pypcd' has no attribute 'PointCloud'". I may have found an alternative solution though. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah yeah, it looks like the PyPCD library is outdated (i.e. written for Python 2 instead of Python 3)...

Comment: Yea, and the other libraries I'll need to use are significantly more complicated to recreate, and are written in python3.

Comment: There's apparently a Python3 -compatible fork of PyPCD you can install with `pip install -U git+https://github.com/klintan/pypcd.git` :)

Comment: Thanks that actually worked. However, the module spits an error for binary pcd formats so I don't think I can use it either way unfortunately. The error is "ValueError: field '__0000' occurs more than once"